# How to download Word Document File in ionic 3 using Sharepoint File URL

Tags: sharepoint, ionic3

I have a stored pdf, xls, doc, etc.. file in list, I have a actual path of a file URL, I am create documents Gallery in my app with download option, when i'm click download icon i have to download a that particular document.

Working fine for PDF and XLS and XLSX file Tested. **But Word Document(.doc,.docx) File has been not properly downloaded.**

It Shows alert is success. But while opening time it shows, 
**Unable to open the document.File appears to be corrupted** like this.

I have tried

file trasfer plugin

i can't achieve pls help me to solve this problem.

here my tried code.

```
this.download("Sample Document.docx","https://abcd.sharepoint.com/samplesite/Shared Documents/Sample Document.docx");

 download(fileName: string, filePath: any) {
        const url= encodeURI(filePath);
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();      
        fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalRootDirectory + fileName, true).then((entry) => {
          //show toast message as success    
        }, (error) => {
          //show toast message as error        
        });
    }
```

here is my output,

[image]

pls give some idea to download a **word document file**. Is there any other way is available to download a file using url in ionic3?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code.

Please check and let me know if you have any issues.

```html
this.download("sample.docx","https://abcd.sharepoint.com/samplesite/Shared Documents/Sample Document.docx");

 download(fileName: string, filePath: any) {
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();      
        fileTransfer.download(filePath, this.file.externalRootDirectory + fileName, true).then((entry) => {
          //show toast message as success
         console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());    
        }, (error) => {
          //show toast message as error        
        });
    }
```

NOTE : If the error message is still appearing (The file appears to be corrupted).Try with some other files in share-point list or add more files and try with them.This is a working code and the issue may be in share-point side.

Comment: No its not working all document.  It will return error code 1.

Comment: so i changed my code back. with encodeURI() method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have to find other way.

Comment: FYI - I am doubting if the docx files we need to turn off the protected views in the ‘Trust Center’ settings of file:[link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-protected-view-microsoft-wor)

If it is not helpful please ignore.
Thanks